# Connect to a derby database on a network server

Tags: derby

I have an eclipse scout program with a derby database in server mode. Since now the database is on the localhost and works perfectly as it should. Now I have a little raspberry pi server in my network and I want to put the database there.
I already did the port forwarding in my router and tried to

#### start the derby server with

```
startNetworkServer -h 0.0.0.0
```

#### I also tried

```
startNetworkServer -h 192.168.178.10
```

When I try to connect to my database using ij, the following error appears:
    ERROR 08001: java.net.ConnectException: Fehler beim Herstellen der Verbindung zu Server 192.168.178.10 auf Port 1.527 mit Meldung Connection refused: connect.

#### This is my ij command:

```
connect 'jdbc:derby://192.168.178.10:1527/media/usbspeicher/srv/smb_freigabe/liris/LIRIS/sampleDB;user=xxxx;password=xxxx';
```

So which steps are necessary for getting it work?

Comment: Perhaps there is a firewall on your your Rasberry Pi Server? Perhaps there is a firewall on your client machine?

Comment: I haven't installed a firewall on my Raspberry Pi, on the client machine the firewall is deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the mistake. You need of course run the derby server on that machine that provides the db. If you run it on a linux machine start your path after the port with a // .